# how to make button that plays sample of all audio files in page in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, audio

I have code that dynamically loads audio files from a directory. Right now they play/pause when a div is clicked. Here is my javascript doing that:

```
function get_list_of_files_from_html( html_string ){
       var el = document.createElement( 'html' );
       el.innerHTML = html_string;

       var list_of_files = el.getElementsByTagName( 'a' ); 

     var return_string ='<UL>';

       for(var i=5; i < list_of_files.length ; i++){
           var current_string = list_of_files[i];
           var new_string  = 
 current_string.toString().replace
(/http:\/\/www.website.com\/~user\/programming\//g,'');
           var brand_new = new_string.replace('.mp3','');
            return_string += '<div class="floating"    
onclick="playAudio(\'audio_tag_id'+i+'\')" >'+brand_new+'<audio 
id="audio_tag_id'+i+'"> <source src = "'+current_string+'" 
type="audio/mpeg"></audio>';
             return_string += '</div>';
       }


            return return_string;
        }

function playAudio(tag_id){
  var audio= document.getElementById(tag_id);
return audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
}
```

I want to make a button that plays only like five seconds of each audio file and runs through them in order. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this?

Comment: Could you use 5s audio clips instead of the full file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to work asynchronously, so it's a ping-pong between the main code and a callback. Something like this:

```
// The click event handler 
function onPlayClicked(event){ 
    if (!window.HTMLAudioElement){
        console.write("Error: no audio"); 
        return;
    }

    // toggle the state of the playlist not the actual music player
    isPlaying = !isPlaying; 
    if (isPlaying) startPlaying();
    else resetList();  // if clicked while playing
}

// sets timer and plays current
function startPlaying(){  
    if (isPlaying){ // just checking that no one pressed the STOP in the meantime...
      setTimout(done, 5000); // timer callback and miliseconds
      playAudio(); 
    }
}


// stops this song and starts next. Callback from timer 
function done(){
    if (nowPlaying == lastSongIndex(){
        pauseAudio();
        resetPlaylist();
        return;
    }
    if (isPlaying){
       pauseAudio();
       nowPlaying++;
       startPlaying();
}

// plays current audio
function playAudio(){
    // Friendly advice: don't use getElementByTag. There may be other 'a's. 
    audioList = document.getElementById('audiolist');
    audioURL = audioList[nowPlaying]; // nowPlaying advanced by done()
    urlregex = '/http:\/\/www.website.com\/~user\/programming\//g';
    audioData = audioUrl.remove(urlregex).replace('.mp3','');

    player = document.getElementById('audioplayer');
    player.src = audioData;
    player.play();
}

function pauseAudio(){
    player = document.getElementById('audioplayer');
    player.pause();
}

function reset(){
    pauseAudio();
    nowPlaying = 0;
    isPlaying = false;
    // Unpress the button 
}
// you can easily fill in the rest.
```

For understanding the audio control in HTML5 see [this for an overview](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) at w3schools, and this [as an example](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp) on the same website.

Also note friendly remark: Javascript uses camelCase as a convention and not snake_case as in Python.